# Importing a huge csv data file and using the header to access columns using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

I need to import a huge csv data file (6880 columns) and I need to be able use the column headers to access it.

What's the best way?

Speed isn't important.  Clarity is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FasterCSV](https://rubygems.org/gems/fastercsv) (also [available as CSV in Ruby 1.9 standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011395/what-is-ruby-1-9-standard-csv-library)) should be able to do the trick. You can use column headers to access a row's data:

```
require 'fastercsv'
FasterCSV.foreach(csv_file, {:headers => true, :return_headers => false, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all} ) do |row|
    puts row[:some_column_header] # Would be "Some Column Header" in the csv file.
end
```

Comment: Does FasterCSV automatically use the first row as headers?

Comment: No, you need to specify `headers: true`