# What is Ruby 1.9 standard CSV library?

Tags: ruby, csv, fastercsv

When I try the FasterCSV gem on my application I get this error:

```
Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard
CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus
support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding
engine.
```

By the way, I'm using Rails 3, Ruby 1.9.2, and Rubygems 1.4.

Can someone explain to me please how to use the standard CSV library for Ruby 1.9. I don't
have any idea at all because I'm very new to Rails.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 has adopted FasterCSV as its built-in CSV library. However, it's in the standard library rather than Ruby 1.9's core, so you need to manually require it in your application.

After adding a

```
require 'csv'
```

to your code, you can then do things such as

```
CSV.parse("this,is,my,data")
```

See [Ruby 1.9's standard library CSV documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/csv/rdoc/index.html) for information on using the library.

Comment: Thank You so much. How I wish I can vote for your answer but the system is telling me to have at least 15 reputation. What do the parameters in  CSV.parse("this,is,my,data") mean? I know thiss is too much too ask but I'm really new to ruby on rails.

Comment: those are not parameters... that's just an example he's giving of a string "this,is,my,data" that is being parsed

Comment: Thank you so much. All I thought those are parameters. I already solved the problem. I already know how to import CSV data in Ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score -6):

See how I solved this problem!

```
require 'fastercsv'
require 'csv'

secrecy_levels_array = [['SUPERSECRET', 'Supersecret Data', "Tell No One"],
['SEMISECRET', 'Semisecret Data', 'Tell Some People'],
['UNSECRET', 'Unsecret Data', 'Tell Everyone']]

puts '\n'
secrecy_levels_array.each do |line|
  puts line.to_csv
end
```

Comment: -1 You didn't even bother to understand the existing three-year-old question & answer before posting. If you're coming in after three years your answer should be more up-to-date, but it is not.