# Problem with TXT file extraction in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have data file as in format of TXT , I like to parse the URL field from TXT file using the below ruby code

```
f = File.open(txt_file, "r")
f.each_line { |line|
  rows = line.split(',')
  rows[3].each do |url|
    next if url=="URL"
    puts url
  end
}
```

TXT contains:

```
name,option,price,URL
"x", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "123.40","http://domain.com/xym.jpg"
"x", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "111.34","http://domain.com/yum.jpg"
```

output:

```
0
```

Why does the output come from the option field "0,0,0,0,0,0"? How do I skip this and get the URL field?

Environment 
ruby 1.8.7
rails 2.3.8
gem 1.3.7

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out a CSV parsing tool to make this easier:

```
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'faster_csv'

 FasterCSV.foreach(txt_file, :quote_char => '"', 
        :col_sep =>',', :row_sep =>:auto) do |row|
   puts row[3] if row[3] != "URL"
   break
 end
```

Also, I think you're misunderstanding how the `split()` would work.  If you run `split()` against one row from your file, you're going to get back an array of `columns` for that single row, not a multidimensional array as `rows[3].each` would suggest.

Comment: In 1.9 it's `require 'csv'` since Faster_CSV replaced the old CSV.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Before reading, I completely agree with the answer by Jeff Swensen, I'll leave my answer here regardless.

I'm not entirely sure what your inside loop is for (`rows[3].each`) Because you can't convert a single line into a 'row' when you only have a single URL. You could split by the `**` characters and return an Array of urls but then you still need to remove the extra double quotes, or you could use a Regular Expression, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

f = DATA
urls = f.readlines.map do |line|
  line[/([^"]+)"\*\*/, 1] 
end
urls.compact!

p urls

__END__
name ,option,price, **URL**
"x", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "123.40",**"http://domain.com/xym.jpg"**
"x", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "111.34",**"http://domain.com/yum.jpg"**
```

The call to `compact` is needed because `map` will insert `nil` objects when you hit something that doesn't match that expression. For the `String#[]` method, see [here](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.2/String#%5B%5D-instance_method)

Comment: Hi injekt Thanks, actually the TXT file here act as a MySQL dump It has 20 columns but I want to parse nearly 8 columns value enough instead of all in TXT file. Here I posted my problem faced on URL field alone remaining fields parsed perfectly (stored multiple tables relation).

Answer (score 1):

The reason that "0" is the result is that your code is blindly splitting on the comma char when you seem to be expecting parsing CSV-style (where column values may contain delimiter chars if the entire column value is enclosed in quotes. I highly suggest using a csv parser. If you are using Ruby 1.9.2, then you will already have access to the [FasterCSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011395/what-is-ruby-1-9-standard-csv-library) library.

Comment: Thanks buruzaemon and I'm using ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the fields you want are always surrounded by double quotations, you can use that as the basis for extracting rather than the comma.

```
File.open(txt_file) do |f|
  f.each_line do |l|
    cols = l.scan(/(?<!\\)"(.*?)(?<!\\)"/)
    cols[3].tap{|url| puts url if url}
  end
end
```

- In your code, the opened IO is not closed. This is a bad practice. It is better to use a block so that you do not forget to close it.
- The two `(?<!\\)"` in the regex match non-escaped double quotations. They use negative lookbehind.
- `.*?` is a non-greedy match, which avoids a match from exceeding a non-escaped double quotation.
- `tap` is to avoid repeating the `cols[3]` operation twice in `puts` and `if`.

**Edit again**

If you use ruby 1.8.7, you can either

- update your regex engine to oniguruma by following easy steps here, http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/

or

- replace the regex. `tap` cannot be used also. Use the following instead:

.

```
File.open(txt_file) do |f|
  f.each_line do |l|
    cols = l.scan(/(?:\A|[^\\])"(.*?[^\\]|)"/)
    url = cols[3]
    puts url if url
  end
end
```

I would recomment using oniguruma. It is a new regex engine introduced since ruby 1.9, and is much powerful and faster than the one used in ruby 1.8. It can be installed easily on ruby 1.8.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I miss the end of line in my question i.e "f.close". when i run ur code getting an error "undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<!\\)"(.*?)(?<!\\)""

Comment: @prabu I saw you added the information that you use ruby 1.8.7. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The data is in CSV format, but if all you want to do is grab the *last* field in the string, then do just that:

```
text =<<EOT
name,option,price,URL
"x", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "123.40","http://domain.com/xym.jpg"
"x", "0,0,0,0,0,0", "111.34","http://domain.com/yum.jpg"
EOT

require 'pp'
text.lines.map{ |l| l.split(',').last }
```

If you want to clean up the double-quotes and trailing line-breaks:

```
text.lines.map{ |l| l.split(',').last.gsub('"', '').chomp }
# => ["URL", "http://domain.com/xym.jpg", "http://domain.com/yum.jpg"]
```