# Upload and import data from CSV file in Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

I want to write a module for uploading a CSV file in my application. Also, I want to import the data from that file to one of my tables in my Rails application.

In my application there is a model named "Book" which has four fields: `name`, `author`, `publication_date` and `publisher_name`.

I want to give user the ability to upload a CSV file with the format:

- first column for `name`
- second column for `author`
- third for `publication_date`
- fourth for `publisher_name`.

Also I want to add the validation so that upload will happen only when the file is of the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [FasterCSV](http://rubygems.org/gems/fastercsv) gem to do that.First install it and later in your model do like this:

```
    require 'csv'

       validates_format_of :book, :with => /^.+\.(csv)$/,
       :message => 'A .csv file is required.'

    records = CSV.foreach('yourpath/tocsvfile/filename.csv').map do |row|     
    Book.create!({
        :name              => row[0], 
        :author            => row[1], 
        :publication_date  => row[2], 
        :publisher_name    => row[3],
    })
end
```

For more information about CSV,you can find it [here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html)

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Ruby comes with CSV in its standard library, so it's not necessary to load another gem. And, BTW, [that IS FasterCSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011395/what-is-ruby-1-9-standard-csv-library).

Comment: Well ruby adopted the FasterCSV as its Standard CSV library see this SO top answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011395/what-is-ruby-1-9-standard-csv-library

Comment: @theTinMan Oops misjudged your comment.Apologies.

Comment: I know. Feel free to remove both of yours if you want.

Comment: @theTinMan That Wont be necessary.And BTW can you edit my answer as per your comments.

Comment: I *can* edit it, but I won't because that would be changing the content of your answer. Changing formatting, and grammar is OK, but I won't change the meaning.

Comment: @theTinMan OK,no problem :)

Comment: @theTinMan I would like to know the feedback for my answer.Can you share.